# Consuming Json from yahoo finance using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-web

I'm trying to get some financial data from yahoo finance using java / spring RestTemplate. 
Suppose I need the data for IBM, the link would be something like this: 
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/IBM?formatted=true&modules=incomeStatementHistory%2CcashflowStatementHistory%2CbalanceSheetHistory%2CincomeStatementHistoryQuarterly%2CcashflowStatementHistoryQuarterly%2CbalanceSheetHistoryQuarterly%2Cearnings
which is a nice formatted JSON with all the data I need:

```
{
"quoteSummary": {
"result": [
{
"cashflowStatementHistoryQuarterly": {
"cashflowStatements": [
{
"maxAge": 1,
"endDate": {
"raw": 1459382400,
"fmt": "2016-03-31"
},
"netIncome": {
"raw": -5490000,
"fmt": "-5.49M",
"longFmt": "-5,490,000"
},
"depreciation": {
"raw": 16849000,
"fmt": "16.85M", ... etc
```

But when I try to open the same link using RestTemplate: 
using a code like:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<String>response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
```

The result I'm getting back in response is very different, it looks like this:

```
<200 OK,{"quoteSummary":{"result":[{}],"error":null}},{X-YQL-Host=[pprd3-node7511-lh2.manhattan.ir2.yahoo.com], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-Yahoo-Request-Id=[6s0s3nlbqhlls], Cache-Control=[max-age=1, stale-while-revalidate=15], Content-Type=[application/json; charset=utf-8], Vary=[Origin], Content-Length=[45], Date=[Mon, 08 Aug 2016 19:00:12 GMT], Age=[2], Server=[ATS], Via=[http/1.1 media-ncache-api14.prod.media.ir2.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSfW]), http/1.1 media-ncache-api15.prod.media.ir2.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ]), http/1.1 media-router-api3.prod.media.ir2.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSfW]), https/1.1 r07.ycpi.loa.yahoo.net (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSfW])], Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=0], Connection=[keep-alive], Y-Trace=[BAEAQAAAAACPmeCQTRIz3QAAAAAAAAAAOEHjlsK9d9kAAAAAAAAAAAAFOZQGmKa_AAU5lAap7rIUoHdnAAAAAA--]}>
```

Any idea how can I get the same result I'm getting in the browser?

Thank you

Comment: You're printing the `ResponseEntity` object (called `response.toString()`). `ResponseEntity` represents the entire HTTP response. Instead, use `ResponseEntity#getBody()` to get the response body content and do what you will (print?) with it.

Comment: Or are you referring to the `quoteSummary` being empty? That might have to do with your cookies (are you logged in to your Yahoo account) and/or other headers. Check in your browser's network console what headers you are sending and reproduce those with `RestTemplate`.

Comment: response.getBody() gives this: {"quoteSummary":{"result":[{}],"error":null}}

I wonder what other header? is Yahoo website not liking a connection from RestTemplate?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I tried in chrome dev tools, in the network tab ->  xhr tab, I can't see any headers.. am I missing something?

Comment: In the `Headers` tab, there should be _General_, _Response Headers_, and _Request Headers_. Select `All` instead of `XHR`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120460/discussion-between-charbel-and-sotirios-delimanolis).